# Can't find "/sys/devices/system/cpu/sched_mc_power_savings"

Tags: kernel, power-management, cpu

I'm currently working on Ubuntu 12.04 x64. A lot of manuals about power saving in Linux tells about using parameters `/sys/devices/system/cpu/sched_mc_power_savings` and `/sys/devices/system/cpu/sched_smt_power_savings`, but they don't exists in my OS. Is it about 3.X kernel improvements? Is there any similar ways of turning CPU scheduling in power save mode on Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: Possible Duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter/285681#285681 , The questin : Is there any similar ways of turning CPU scheduling in power save mode on Ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 0):

That is strange -- sched_mc_power_savings seems to exist on my system.  I am running 12.04 x64, fairly vanilla install.  What are the contents of your /sys/devices/system/cpu directory?  Mine looks like the following:

```
mike@cobbler:~$ ls -la /sys/devices/system/cpu/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root    0 Aug  5 15:21 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root    0 Aug  5 15:21 ..
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root    0 Aug  5 15:21 cpu0
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root    0 Aug  5 15:21 cpu1
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    0 Aug  5 15:21 cpufreq
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    0 Aug  5 15:21 cpuidle
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Aug  5 17:04 kernel_max
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Aug  5 17:04 offline
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Aug  5 15:21 online
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Aug  5 17:04 possible
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Aug  5 15:36 present
--w------- 1 root root 4096 Aug  5 17:04 probe
--w------- 1 root root 4096 Aug  5 17:04 release
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Aug  5 15:21 sched_mc_power_savings
```

Comment: ls -a /sys/devices/system/cpu/
.   cpu0  cpufreq  kernel_max  online    present  release
.. cpu1  cpuidle  offline     possible  probe